# Cannot assign the ouput of `base64.decode()` to a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to import a base 64 encoded graphic to use as a canvas background. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html), base64.decode takes 2 arguments: input and output. I don't understand how to assign the ouput of `base64.decode()` to the variable `background_image`. These are the two lines of code in question:

```
background_image = base64.decode(background_image.background_image, x.png) 
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=background_image), anchor=NW)
```

This is the version of my reduced program.

```
#imported modules
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import base64

#imported files
import background_image # a .py file containing the base64 encoded graphic string 

'''...stuff'''

background_image = base64.decode(background_image.background_image, x.png) 
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=background_image), anchor=NW)

'''...more stuff'''
```

Comment: Where do you have your information from that decode takes two arguments of which one is the output? That's not true. It *returns* it's output. I presume your problem is with trying to instantiate a PhotoImage from a string, instead of a a PIL image. You need to create an PIL.Image via a StringIO-object wrapping the background_image-contents, and use that to instantiate the PhotoImage.

Comment: Ups. I just saw that you are using a different function than I presumed. Tim has given a correct answer for that part. And the rest of my comment is not entirely correct, either - I saw the wrong documentation for that. However, you still can't do it the way you want, as PhotoImage either takes a file-like object, or base64-encoded data as string. So you can skip the whole decode, and use PhotoImage(data=background_image.background_image)

Comment: You mean like this `background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=background_image.background_image)` and like this `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=background_image, anchor=NW)` ?

Comment: Yes, according to http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm that should work.

Comment: @deets that's what I did but i get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html#base64.decode) more carefully:

```
base64.decode(input, output)
```

> Decode the contents of the binary `input` file and write the resulting binary data to the `output` file. `input` and `output` *must be file objects*. `input` will be read until `input.read()` returns an empty `bytes` object.

If anything, you should be using [`base64.b64decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode).

```
background_image = base64.b64decode(background_image.background_image)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfect if I want to create an empty image `file` and write to it `fh.write(base64.b64decode(background_image.background_image))` but I want to this `background_image = base64.b64decode(background_image.background_image)` and then this `background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=background_image)` to put the image in the canvas background.